# Vector Vector C ++

Tags: c++, vector

Vector Vector C ++
Hi, I do not understand the syntax of nested vectors to simulate an array, I have the following code.

```
vector< vector< float> > myvector (n, vector < float> (2));
```

But I do not quite understand how it works, especially where you specify the size of the vectors and the vectors in it, if you want to make a resize so that my vector vector has specified dimensions how can I resize internal vectors?
Something like changing `vec [10] [2]` to `vec [10] [5]` (changing the second dimension)

In addition to how to make copies with multidimensional vectors something like:

```
vector< int> myvector (myVectorToCopy, myVectorToCopy+myVectorToCopy.size());
```

But with several dimensions.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to resize a simple vector, such as `std::vector<int> a;`? Do you know how to access the elements of a vector? Combine the two.

Comment: You want matrixes. You could find C++ libraries for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<vector<float>>` means you are creating a vector which contains a vector of floats. The constructor argument means you are creating a vector of size `n` where each element of vector is a vector of floats having size 2.

To resize the `vector<vector<float>>`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    A[i].resize(newSize);
```

Alternatively you could use:

```
A.assign(n,vector<float>(newSize));
```

To make a copy of multidimensional vector use constructor:

```
vector<vector<float>> B(A);
```

Answer (score 1):

Vectors in C++ will resize automatically if you fill them up and try to add more to them. If you know the exact size of your vector, I would suggest switching to `std::array`, however you will lose the ability to resize them at runtime.

`std::vector::operator[]` has an overload to return a reference to the `T` used to create the template (in your case `T` is `std::vector`, the nested one). If you know the index in the outer vector, you could do something like:

```
myVec[0].resize(5);
```

This will resize your nested vector at position 0 to 5 elements.

Copying is much the same as accessing:

```
std::copy(std::begin(VecToCopy), std::end(VecToCopy), std::begin(VecToFill));
```

Using `std::begin` last might not be what you want but its just an example.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array